# Is it possible in grails to disable persistence of a domain class?

Tags: grails, groovy, persistence

To get around this I have to move such classes to src/groovy. It would be nice to have all of my domain model classes in the domains directory rather than split them up.

**Update 1:**
This is a [popular](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Apopularissues-panel) (look for GRAILS-2515) requested feature on the Grails Jira page. If anyone is interested in this feature you can vote and track it [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2515).

**Update on GRAILS-2515:**
static mapWith = "none" should do the trick in 1.3.5.

Comment: don't call save on the object?? Not really certain the question is clear... maybe providing more context might be helpful

Comment: it will still create tables for that class.

Comment: Why not just make it a POGO in src/groovy?

Comment: @Rob Hruska - Thats what I'm doing as a workaround (read the first line of my question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only possible to mark certain properties on the domain object as 'transient' so that they are not persisted to the database. Otherwise, all domain objects are persisted.

**UPDATE**

With the most recent release of Grails 1.3.5 (released Oct 4 2010) it is **now possible** to disable persistence of a domain class. Add the following to the domain class:

```
static mapWith = "none"
```

There is a [JIRA ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-2515) with further details.

Answer (score 3):

If I might add 2 words to your question: against convention! Grails is all about convention over configuration and doing what you'd like to do is against it.

Comment: convention works 95% of time. but sometimes a few brave ones have to break away from it :)

Comment: Yeah... and then there comes the new developer, hoping someone knew what they were doing and faces the imminent disappointment...

Comment: The concept is "convention over [preferred to] configuration", not "convention no configuration possible".

Comment: You're right... but still conforming to the convention makes life easier for everybody, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not.