# Is it possible in grails to disable persistence of a domain class dynamically with inheritance

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My question is related to/or identical to 
[Is it possible in grails to disable persistence of a domain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795700/is-it-possible-in-grails-to-disable-persistence-of-a-domain-class)

I am using grails 2.2.1 where I tried to turn off a domain class by putting
static mapWith = "none"
gorm creates the database table, and calling .save() will actually put an entry to the database.  So the mapWith flag did nothing for me.  I also cannot find any documentation regarding the mapWith flag.  Is there a replacement in Grails 2?

Update on sept 16 with code

```
package test

class Person {


  String name
  static constraints = {
  }

  static mapping = {
    version false
    tablePerHierarchy false
    table 'psn'
  }
}
-------------------

package test

class Employer extends Person{

  static mapWith = 'none'

  String title
  static constraints = {

  }

  static mapping = {
    version false
    tablePerHierarchy false
    table 'emplyr'
  }
}

---------
package test

class Employee extends Person{


  String description

  static constraints = {
  }

  static mapping = {
    version false
    tablePerHierarchy false
    table 'emplyee'
  }
}
```

I would assume Employer should not be treated as a domain object.  However, when I perform, a Person.list(), this sql was shown:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.name as name0_0_, this_1_.description as descript2_1_0_, this_2_.title as title2_0_, case when this_1_.id is not null then 1 when this_2_.id is not null then 2 when this_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_ from psn this_ left outer join emplyee this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id left outer join emplyr this_2_ on this_.id=this_2_.id limit ?
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from psn this_ left outer join emplyee this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id left outer join emplyr this_2_ on this_.id=this_2_.id
```

Why would it join emplyr????? My purpose is to eliminate this table join when this is mark as "none".  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code, the `static mapWith = "none"` should work.

Comment: @Alidad Wrong. It **works**, there is no question of "should" :)

Comment: Make sure you are **not** adding `mapWith` inside `mapping` block.

Comment: @Groovy When you say that something didn't worked for you, is good to attach some code :-)

Comment: I am still trying to reproduce the problem

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific,  please see if you can answer it.